# How to list registered icons in angular components?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

If `Component A` registered `Icon X` using 

`import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

and if I want to use `Icon X` in `Component B` without registering.

so how can I list all registered icons from all available components? so that I can see registered icons and use from that list.

I know one solution would be registering icons in `app.component.ts` or `root-component` would solve this problem, but I have some implementation restriction and don't want to do this way.

Comment: You can't list them without being explicit. As you said, simply register them in your app **module** and use them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the implementation, these are the only getters MatIconRegistry has:
[image]

So, no it doesn't seem to be possible. You can get an icon if you know its' URL or name.

Comment: can you please provide implementation for `getNamedSvgIcon`?  it returns `Observable<svgElement>` how do I use it in HTML part?

Comment: Normally you would use `<mat-icon>` element in your HTML https://material.angular.io/components/icon/examples